# How to establish a file server?

Tags: file-transfer, file-sharing

I want to build a file server to share huge file in a company intranet using windows XP.

I want to the client side can download and pause and continue downloading.
And the client side can use most of popular downloading tool to request files from the server.

Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use uTorrent and set yourself up as a private tracker then create the .torrent files people can download from a central location. Would be less stress on your box since the files are p2p.

Here are a few short guides.

http://bootstrike.com/Articles/CreateTorrent/

http://filesharefreak.com/2008/10/08/share-private-torrents-with-utorrents-embedded-tracker/

http://filesharefreak.com/tutorials/utorrent-make-your-own-bittorrent-tracker/

Try to look past the file pirating stigma put on torrents this is what the system was designed for :)

Or

You can use the Windows built in file sharing system and the client could use Teracopy to download the files.

Comment: Will try uTorrent.And I think Teracopy doesn't suit for me.Because if I pause and close Teracopy and open it again, the file disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on how you want to share the files - windows file sharing is what i've seen most places use. If you want to use a download manager, you could probably set up a webserver - some flavour of apache would be a possibility, but there's simpler alternatives.

If you can dedicate hardware to it, i'd suggest something like [openfiler](http://www.openfiler.com/) or [freenas](http://freenas.org/)  which would give you far more flexibility